# Time slot definition in a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, time

I need to define a time slot over midnight. When the script is triggered it should test if the time is between 05.00pm and 08.00am. Only if it's true an command should run. I tried the following and it works, but not over midnight. Any idea  how to realize it?

```
#!bin/bash
hr=`date +%H%M`  
if test $hr -ge 1700 -a $hr -lt 0800  
then        
echo "success"

fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "over midnight"?

Comment: This seems more like homework. It makes more sense using a crontab file.

Answer (score 2):

To run between 5pm and 7:59am (exclusive of 8am):

```
case $(date +%H) in
  (17|18|19|20|21|22|23|00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07) echo run;;
  (*) echo do not run;;
esac
```

... to include all of the 8am timeframes, include 8 in the first list. No need to include the minutes in the `date` command.

Comment: complete different approach than mine but very interresting for me. Works fine. Have learned a lot regarding Bash scripting and the possibilities of 'case'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but one issue I see is that a number cannot be both greater than 1700 and less than 0800, so your if statement will always return false.  You need to use an `or` operator instead of an `and`.

Here is what I came up with that seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
hr=$(date +%H%M)
if [[ $hr -ge "1700" || $hr -lt "0800" ]]; then
echo "success"
fi
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast response to my question. Your suggestion looks simple and reasonable, but unfortunately it results in the following msg but I miss the point.                                                                      #test.sh: line 4: [[: 0800: value too great for base (error token is "0800")

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It was my fold. After correcting it, everything seems to work fine.